# Error: A script element with a defer attribute must not have a type attribute with the value module

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I have this code in the `<head>`-section:

```
<script defer src="./static/js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

The validator on validator.w3.org gives me the error: "**A script element with a defer attribute must not have a type attribute with the value module.**"

The javascript works fine and I am trying to understand the reason for the error. What can I do to solve the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script.

> The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by default.

The error message is a little bit confusing. It suggests there is something wrong with the type-attribute. It would be a little bit more clear if it would say something like: "**A script element with a type attribute with the the value module should not have a defer attribute.**"